# How to get facebook likes, shares, and comment count for a post url without using fql?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, social-media

I need facebook like, share and comment count by passing the post url ("www.example.com/exampleblog") without using fql(as fql is not supported in v2.1).

i dont want the below one

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT url, 
share_count, like_count, comment_count, 
total_count,commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, 
click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://example.example.com/'
```

can anyone suggest an alternative to the above , that supports api v2.1?

Answer (score 1):

In Graph v2.1, Facebook added the [URL node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/url) to query details about any given URL. It'll give you plenty of details, **including share/comment counts**.

Comment: thank you, but this doesn't solve my problem. what i coud get out of URL /?id={url}  is share count alone. also note that here share count= likes+ comments+ shares, i want these three as a separate entity( fql provides me). also note: the "url node" api gives me a comment count which remains zero for all the time regardless of how many comments i have added.  :(

Comment: Ah - seems like there isn't a way of getting that extra data without FQL.